# When joining tables duplicate data is being returned from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

**Email_tbl**:

```
plcid       Ecode
----------- -----------
23          001646
24          001646
25          E004
25          2274
25          2208
25          1868
```

I have another table `Employee`:

```
Ecode   Ename
E004     jaseem
2274     jasir
2208      deepu
1868       rupa
001646     shafeer
```

I want to get `Ename` of `plcid=25` so I use this query here:

```
SELECT em.Ename
FROM dbo.Email_tbl e
JOIN dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl em ON em.Ecode IN (SELECT Ecode
                                               FROM Email_tbl
                                               WHERE plcid = 25)
```

but my result is coming wrong. What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  em.Ename
FROM    dbo.Email_tbl e
        JOIN dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl em ON em.Ecode = e.ECode
WHERE e.plcid = 25
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you even joining the tables? And why are there 3 answers 'fixing' an unnecessary join?

```
SELECT em.Ename
FROM dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl em
WHERE em.Ecode IN (SELECT Ecode
                   FROM Email_tbl
                   WHERE plcid = 25)
```

Comment: You could use EXISTS as well.

Comment: I don't think you can. You want specific values here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT emp.Ename
    FROM Email_tbl e INNER JOIN Employee emp ON (e.Ecode = emp.Ecode)
    WHERE e.plcid = 25
```

This will result in multiple rows because multiple rows in Employee have the Ecode for PLCID = 25